# Definition of continuity in practice

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, self-learning

In general I have a problem to recognise if a function is continuous or not. I simply don't know where I should start to actually see it.

Here there is an example of my problem that I found in a proof in a book.

Let $\Delta$ be the Cantor space and define the set $C$ as

$$ C:= \{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{3^n} : a_n=0 \text{ or } a_n=2 \}. $$

> ***Proposition:*** The Cantor set $\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $C$.
>
> ***Proof:*** Define $$\phi (a_1, a_2, \dots ) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2a_n}{3^n}.$$ Then $\phi$ is *continous*, one-to-one and surjective. Hence, it is a homeomorphism. $\square$

Now, *why exactly $\phi$ is continous?*

I simply don't know where to start when I find statements like this one.

Any feedback or help is welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: To the Moderators: I am aware that the title is a bit vague, but it is very difficult for me to define this problem concretely, without using an example. That's why the title is fuzzy. Still, the content I think is fairly clear. I hope it is not a problem in general.

Comment: Think about what effect small changes in $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ have on $\phi$.  If you like, I can spell out the details in an answer.

Comment: @TravisJ: That would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $\phi$ is continuous if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ so that if $\Vert x-y\Vert<\delta$ then $\Vert \phi(x)-\phi(y)\Vert<\epsilon$.

Suppose that $\Vert x-y\Vert<\delta$.  Then $|x_{i}-y_{i}|<\delta$ for each $i$.  Hence 
\begin{align*}
|\phi(x)-\phi(y)| &= \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x_{i}}{3^{n}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2y_{i}}{3^{n}}\right|\\
            &=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(x_i-y_i)}{3^{n}}\right| \\
            &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2|x_{i}-y_{i}|}{3^{n}} \\
            &< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2\delta}{3^{n}} \\
            &= c\delta \\
            &< \epsilon\end{align*}
If $\delta < \epsilon/c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer (there is a typo on the second line, where you use the norm, instead of the absolute value for $\phi (x - y)$)! However, I do have a problem in following your explanation, because I know the definition of continuity, but I am at loss when it is a matter of applying it to *"higher"* mathematical situations. Thus, going back to my example, what is $x$ applied to my example? As I wrote, I am a self-learner and I am kinda slow in getting certain things. :-)

Comment: Moreover, how did you put the $\delta$ on the numerator of the infinite sum?

Comment: Last comment, applying the standard definition of continuity, shouldn't it be $\phi (x) - \phi(y)$ instead of $\phi (x - y)$?

Comment: The edited version shows how the $\delta$ ends up on top.  You are right on the $\phi(x)-\phi(y)$ I will make the easy change.

Comment: @Kolmin, it is corrected now.  Let me know if there is anything that is not understandable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I have three questions, that I will write in two comments.

Comment: **1.** How does the $c$ pops up in the last equality? Should it be something like $c= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2/3^n$?

Comment: **2.** Regarding the overall structure of your proof, the standard way should be to start in the following way, right? *"Let $x \in \Delta$ be arbitrary, and let $\epsilon >0$. Let $y \in \Delta$ be arbitrary. Let $\delta = \epsilon / c$, where $c = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2/3^n$. Then, $|| x - y|| < \delta \Longrightarrow \dots$"*

Comment: **3.** Is there a shortcut through to check the continuity of a function like this one, through the standard definition of continuity based on open sets? Rephrasing, is there a way to check it through *metric* or *topological* tools?

Comment: Again, really thanks a lot. I hope I did not take advantage of your helpfulness.

Comment: @Kolmin, (1.) Yes, that value is the $c$.  You could determine exactly what that is since the series is geometric, but I figured that wasn't important in this case.  (2.) Looks good.  (3.) I'm not certain.  I know there are many equivalent characterizations of continuity, but I don't see a nice way to apply any to this particular function.  My general philosophy is: if I can make it work, that method is good enough.  So, realizing that an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof is not too hard, I decided it was "good enough for me."

Comment: Thus, can we say that when there are summations or *similia* $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs are the (so to speak "rule"), while when we start to talk about sets and so on, we can start to think about topological proofs? Again, really thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kolmin, It's really hard to give rules, but if I was forced to give a rule, I would say that in an analysis/metric space setting $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs are the rule--mostly because all the definitions are given in $\epsilon-\delta$ terms.  In a more abstract topological setting one might favor other methods--it just all depends on how things are defined.